# will we loose precision by implicit conversion

Tags: java, implicit-conversion, implicit

There is a question in Java past exam paper that brothers me:

> With implicit conversion of primitive data types, you can lose precision and get incorrect results.
>
> A True, B False
>
> The key to the answer is A: True

I think it will neither lose precision nor get incorrect results. I know the explicit conversion can lose precision and get incorrect results but not implicit one.

For example:

```
int i = 9;

short s = 3;

i = s; // implicit conversion, neither loose 
      //precision nor incorrect results

s = i; // compile error, do we call this implicit conversion? 
       //if yes, then the answer to question 3 is True, 
       //but I don't think this is an implicit conversion, 
       //so I think answer is false.
```

As states on the notes:

> Implicit type conversion: The programmer does not make any attempt to convert the type, rather the type is automatically converted by the system under certain circumstances.

Could anyone please advise?

Many thanks.

Comment: Richard so you mean implicit conversion will not lose precision right? the answer is B, false right?

Comment: An implicit conversion is when the compiler accepts the code by putting in an implicit conversion. If there is a compile error, there is no conversion.

Answer (score 6):

Answer = A

```
    float f = Long.MAX_VALUE;
    System.out.println(Long.MAX_VALUE);
    System.out.printf("%.0f", f);
```

output

```
9223372036854775807
9223372036854776000
```

Answer (score 3):

There are some cases where the compiler will allow an implicit conversion, but you may still lose precision.  For example:

```
long a = Long.MAX_VALUE;  // 9223372036854775807
double b = a;             // 9223372036854776000
```

See the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1) for more details on this.

Comment: I've not found any difficulties with this program

Comment: @RichardTingle: Define "difficulties".  `b` does not represent the same numeric value as `a`; thus we've lost precision.

Comment: In this program both intIn and intOut print 9223372036854775807;         Long intIn=Long.MAX_VALUE;
        
        System.out.println(intIn);
        
        float floatTest=intIn;
        
        System.out.println(floatTest);
        
        long intOut=(long)floatTest; 
        
        
        
        System.out.println(intOut);

Comment: I know the second convert is explicit, but if anything that should make matters worse

Comment: And yet Evgeniy Dorofeev's program is problematic (lost precision). Perhaps my JVM is being "clever"

Comment: @RichardTingle: The number stored in `b` is greater than MAX_VALUE.  Thus it "saturates" to MAX_VALUE when you convert back.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3 for the algorithm used here.

Answer (score 1):

There is implicit conversions in assignment operators.  These can lose precision or cause an overflow.  For regular assignments, implicit conversion only happen when the compiler knows it is safe. It can still lose precision, but not cause an overflow.

e.g.

```
final int six = 6;
byte b = six; // compiler uses constant propagation and value is in range.

int five = 5;
byte b2 = five; // fails to compile

double d = 5.5;
five += d; // compiles fine, even though implicit conversion drops the 0.5
// five == 10 not 10.5

five += Double.NaN; // five is now 0 ;)
```